# How can I check a method is called with a specific parameter on a mock object?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

Can you help to achieve the goal I mentioned in the commented block below to complete sample unit test?

Idea is how to check on a mock object, if one of its methods is called with a type instance that has a particular property is set to expected value/

```
private IMyObject stub = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMyObject>();
[TestMethod]
public void MakeMyJob_RecievesValidData_CallsRenderWithCorrectParameter()
{
    SomeUtility.MakeMyJob(5,10,stub);

    stub.AsswertWasCalled(s=>s.Render(Arg<IViewModel>.Is. //What next?
                                            // In order to check if Render is called
                                            // with a IViewModel instance 
                                            // whoose Person.Name property is "Peter"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for argument constraints in Rhino Mocks. I had a go at a few of the frameworks sometime ago - [link](http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2010/01/meet-frameworks-rhino-v-moq-v-jmock.html#scen9). I think you're looking for

`Arg<IViewModel>.Matches (vm => vm.Person.Name == "Peter" )`

Comment: Better link - http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#ArgumentConstraints . Look for section called 'Complex expressions'

Answer (score -1):

Look at the [reference](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx):

```
 stub.AsswertWasCalled(s=>s.Render(Arg<IViewModel>.Property("Person", "John")))
```